# Modal popup created on Wordpress wp.media window is always behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, media-library

I am opening a custom gallery window in my plugin with the following code:

```
    this.window = wp.media({
            title: 'Select images for gallery',
            library: {type: 'image'},
            multiple: 'add',
            button: {text: 'Create Gallery'}
    });
    this.window.open();
```

In my custom layout, I have a tinymce editor which has a Insert Link button which opens a modal popup but it always is hidden by the gallery window I created. I have to close this window to see the modal popup. I have tried other methods like jQuery dialog, thickbox .. all open underneath the gallery window.

Is there any way I can have a modal popup that will be visible on TOP of the gallery window created above ?

Comment: With CSS. Give the modal popup an higher [`z-index`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) value.